# Initializing git repository inside of Intellij project folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, egit

I've always used Eclipse, and something I have never fully understood is the reason for eclipse recommending that I move my project outside of my workspace before initializing a new git repository. I have read the egit documentation about it a million times but don't fully understand the true reason WHY. According to [egit user guide](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.egit.doc%2Fhelp%2FEGit%2FUser_Guide%2FTasks.html), it has to do with the .project file inside of the project folder and the metadata folder inside of the workspace directory. If anyone has insight to what this exactly means, please comment.

Anyways,

I've made the switch to intellij and am just wondering if similar rules / recommendations apply. Is it okay to initialize a git repo inside of my project folder with intellij? Why or why not? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's perfectly fine so that you can optionally share some IDE project metadata in the repository. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839 if you want to not share anything IntelliJ IDEA specific.

Comment: It's just a recommendation, no limitation. A project inside of the workspace can be a Git repository. That is not a problem. But when you change your mind and want to add another project to the same repository later, you would have to move the first project into a subfolder first. In this case, it would have been easier if the first project had already been created as a subfolder in the Git repository (which is typically done outside the workspace). Apart from the fact that moving projects in Eclipse isn't that easy, this recommendation is independent of the IDE used.